# How to pull data from two tables but use one offset and one sort option?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

Phase 1:
So I want to get two types of users information, parent and child.

A parent can have NO child and a child can have NO parent.

For pagination purposes I want to get 50 from both tables but only the child if it has no parent, based on sort of date_account_created.

Phase 2:
The other added complexity is that all children belonging to a parent should be returned as well.

Solution:

Is phase 2 possible to add, if not I can get Phase 1 and then make a separate query for all children and based on the added children.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT PARENT.* CHILDREN.* 
FROM PARENT JOIN CHILDREN ON PARENT.uid != CHILD.uid 
ORDER BY PARENT.created_date, CHILDREN.created_date 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50;
```

Not sure how to do ORDER by since they are different tables?

My stack is Nodejs with Mysql.

```
Update:
Example PARENT table:
pid: 1, uid: 1, date_created August 5, 2019
pid: 2, uid: 2, date_created August 4, 2019
pid: 3, uid: 3, date_created August 15, 2019

Example CHILD table:
cid: 1, uid: 5, date_created August 3, 2019
cid: 2, uid: 1, date_created August 2, 2019
cid: 3, uid: 3, date_created August 15, 2019

Expected Result:
cid: 1, uid: 5, date_created August 3, 2019
pid: 2, uid: 2, date_created August 4, 2019
pid: 1, uid: 1, date_created August 5, 2019
pid: 3, uid: 3, date_created August 15, 2019
```

Comment: Recommend you create an example of your data at http://sqlfiddle.com/.  One question I would have is when you say that 'all children belonging to a parent should be returned,' do you mean that the children of a parent should be sorted according to their parent's date_account_created?

Comment: nope it should be independent of both, let me include examples

Comment: I don't understand your example data... `pid` is parent id, `cid` is child id, but what is `uid`?

Comment: the user id which relates to another table where it includes every user, so I do not want a parent that the child is himself ultimately that is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

```
SELECT PARENT.* CHILDREN.* 
FROM PARENT LEFT JOIN CHILDREN ON PARENT.uid != CHILD.uid 
ORDER BY PARENT.created_date, CHILDREN.created_date 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50;
```

Comment: Yes you will get your expected results

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you are looking for?

```sql
(SELECT 
   uid, 
   created_date, 
   created_date as sort_date 
   FROM parents)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT 
   c.uid as uid, 
   c.created_date as created_date, 
   COALESCE(p.created_date, c.created_date) as sort_date 
   FROM
   children c 
   left join 
    parents p
     on p.uid = c.parent_uid)
ORDER BY sort_date desc
```

You can see it in action in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/917b65/1)

My concept here is that you want to sort the children with their parent, so if a child has a parent, it uses the parent's `created_date` as its `sort_date`. If a child has no parent, it uses its own `created_date` as its `sort_date`.  This is what the `COALESCE` function does for you.

Comment: Where is parent_uid coming from?

Comment: Look at the sqlfiddle link.  Each child has a parent_uid field that indicates the uid of the parent.